# Casting the void pointer and printing with format specifiers

Tags: c, casting, segmentation-fault, void-pointers

Okay this is for a school project but my question has **nothing to do with anything regarding a specific implementation**, nor am I asking for any help regarding the project itself. I am only giving this warning because I want to give context for what I am doing, but this is rather a general question regarding the casting of void pointers, framed within the context of a project... This function I'm writing isn't even FOR the project, it's just something I wrote as a testing mechanism to see if my generation of a data structure is working... and it lead me to a problem involving printf(), format specifiers, and casting.... I basically have to implement a linked-list (called a 'queue' but is not really a queue at all), and I wrote a function to test it.

There is basically a struct called a "Chunk" with some variables (**first** is the index within the larger array that is the first element of a given "Chunk", and **arr** is basically larger_array[c->first], but it's actually a void pointer as such: **void *arr** where c is a pointer to a Chunk) that indicate a position in a larger array. So basically if you have an array like a = {5,7,3,4,6,9,1,2}, and you were given a chunk size of two, you have 4 chunks each of whom have an "arr" void pointer variable which point respectively to 5, then 3, then 6, then 1.

Anyways, I wrote a "print_queue" function (actually a linked-list of Chunks) and yay! It prints all the information as desired, and here is the core part that I will share:

```
 while (index < num_chunks) {
    first = c->first;
    printf("Chunk %d: first is %d and a[%d] is ", index, first, first);
    if (elem_size == LONG_SIZE) /* LONG_SIZE defined above as 8 */
      printf("%ld\n", c->arr);
    else if (elem_size == INT_SIZE) /* INT_SIZE defined above as 4 */
      printf("%d\n", c->arr);
    else if (elem_size == CHAR_SIZE) /* CHAR_SIZE defined above as 1 */
      printf("%c\n", c->arr);

    index++;

    if (c->next != NULL)
      c = c->next;
 }
```

I basically wanted to write a function that would be able to print my linked-list for any of the three types (longs, ints, and chars) for testing purposes while I implement the actual functionality of the project (multithreaded merge-sort). So the code above actually works! This is the output for this array input:

```
 char original[] = {'z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u', 't', 's'};
```

Output:

```
 Chunk 0: first is 0 and a[0] is z
 Chunk 1: first is 2 and a[2] is x
 Chunk 2: first is 4 and a[4] is v 
 Chunk 3: first is 6 and a[6] is t
```

So it works! Yay! However, I get these compiler warnings:

```
mergesort.c: In function 'print_chunk_queue':
mergesort.c:85:7: warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but     argument 2 has type 'void *' [-Wformat]
mergesort.c:87:7: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'void *' [-Wformat]
mergesort.c:89:7: warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'void *' [-Wformat]
```

So what I did was cast all the c->arr 's to (type *) c->arr, but that gave me more warnings about "oh we want an int but you have us an int pointer" so what I did was then:

```
 * ((type *) c->arr)
```

Basically dereferencing my casted void pointer (which is NEVER null! It always is pointing to valid numbers, at least with the input I provided it!), and then that gives me a segmentation fault!. So I'm pretty frustrated because I went from working output with a ton of "warnings" to useless segmentation faults.

EDIT:

definition of the data structure, as requested:

```
typedef struct chunk {
  void *arr;
  struct chunk *next;
  int first;
} Chunk;
```

this is how I am setting the state of a single chunk and creating a linked-list of chunks:

```
  while (index < number_of_chunks) {
    if (index == 0) {
      if ((current = malloc(sizeof(Chunk))) == NULL)
        err(EX_OSERR, "memory allocation has failed\n");
      head = current;
    }
    current->first = (chunk_size * index);
    current->arr = ((char *) array)[current->first];
    current->size = chunk_size;
    if (index != (number_of_chunks - 1)) {
      if ((current->next = malloc(sizeof(Chunk))) == NULL)
        err(EX_OSERR, "memory allocation has failed\n");
      current = current->next;
   }
  else {
    tail = current;
  }
  index += 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the definitions of the data structures?

Comment: How are you setting `arr`? Please show that code. It's worrisome that `printf("%c\n", c->arr)` actually prints the right values since `c->arr` ought to be an address, not a `char`.

Comment: Should I continue to edit my post as people ask questions, or what is the best way? I can't post code in comments

Comment: @JohnKugelman I posted the initialization code for the chunks and the linked-list

Comment: @Windows Yeah, edit your post, that's the best way. Cheers for being so responsive!

Comment: @JohnKugelman Sure thing, it's the least I can do. I used a char pointer because I figured since it is one byte I can use it as a byte unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
current->arr = ((char *) array)[current->first];
```

There should be an `&` here. You want to assign the *address* of the byte to `arr` rather than its *value*.

```
current->arr = &((char *) array)[current->first];
```

If you do that then `arr` will contain an address like it should, which will allow the casts & dereferences to work.

```
printf("%ld\n", *(long *) c->arr);
printf("%d\n",  *(int  *) c->arr);
printf("%c\n",  *(char *) c->arr);
```

Comment: Does the first one need to be a long double? I tried using a format specifier %l but my editor said it doesn't exist, so I used %ld since I had seen that one before, but then gcc told me that (long *) was not allowed, or didn't correspond to %ld? Thanks tremendously for your insight though, it was extremely foolish of me to assign an array element to a pointer so I appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry ^^ I don't mean long double I mean (long int *), but I'll just try what you said again.

Comment: oh my gosh it works. Thank you so much John Kugelman! Do you know why by any chance why ints and longs use a d as their format specifier? P.S. (long *) did work haha. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `int` uses `d`.  `long` uses `ld`.  It just happens that 'int' and 'long' might be the same in your environment.  That is not always the case.  If they do work and not the same size, its UB  (thin ice).

Comment: `d` stands for "decimal". `%i` is a synonym for `%d`. For whatever reason, `%d` is more popular than `%i`.